# How to generate 18 digit code using cursor based on some conditions in Oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I have a table from which I want to generate 18 digit code.

Below is the 18 digit code sample which I want.

`R-AP-AP01-SMT-4567`

Also for generating the above sample code, here is the data and its logic:

1. R - Fix value
2. AP – (2 digit state code from STATE column)
3. EAST- (From ZONE_NAME column from query below
4. SMT – (From FORMAT_CODE column from below query)
5. 4567 – (From Store Code  column from below query)

`SELECT STATE, STORE_CODE, ZONE_NAME FROM TBL_RRSOC_STORE_INFO;`

AND

`select FORMAT_CODE from TBL_SITE_STORE_FORMAT;`

How can it be achieved?

### Update

Below is the table description

```html
Table name:- TBL_RRSOC_STORE_INFO

Name                        Null     Type           
--------------------------- -------- -------------- 
RRSOC_ID                    NOT NULL NUMBER         
STORE_CODE                  NOT NULL NVARCHAR2(55)  
STATE                                NVARCHAR2(55)  
SLP_STATE                            NVARCHAR2(100) 
FORMAT_GROUP                         NVARCHAR2(100) 


Table name:- TBL_SITE_STORE_FORMAT
Name         Null Type          
------------ ---- ------------- 
ID                VARCHAR2(20)  
STORE_FORMAT      VARCHAR2(100) 
ISACTIVE          VARCHAR2(3)   
FORMAT_GROUP      VARCHAR2(100) 
FORMAT_CODE       VARCHAR2(50)
```

Comment: Hi Nad. This question has apparently received a poor reception. We can't know why people downvoted, but we can guess. I think there are two issues (1) no attempt at the problem; (2) begging for help; (3) phraseology that passes the work to another person, rather than accepting that each person ought to do their own work (with some assistance).

Comment: You may find [this discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366264/how-can-we-encourage-new-authors-to-ask-confident-questions) of use. I'd suggest removing pleading messages ("please help") as this may prompt readers to think you of needy or wheedling, even if this is not true in some measurable sense. Similarly, questions of the form "How can I fix this" or "What can I do to fix it" are a better expression of self-actualisation than "Who can help me fix this" or "Can someone tell me".

Comment: Finally, following a great answer below, you asked for modifications that you could have done yourself. This is known here as "asking for free work" and is frowned upon. In order to become a better programmer you need to start doing things on your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you put it, you'd join those tables somehow (cross join is as good as any other, as you didn't explain it better) and concatenate column values.

Something like this:

```
SQL> with
  2  tbl_rrsoc_store_info (state, store_code, zone_name) as
  3    (select 'AP', 'EAST', 'SMT' from dual union all
  4     select 'NY', 'WEST', 'XYZ' from dual
  5    ),
  6  tbl_site_store_format (format_code) as
  7    (select 4567 from dual)
  8  --
  9  select 'R' ||'-'|| r.state ||'-'|| r.store_code ||'-'|| r.zone_name ||'-'|| s.format_code result
 10  from tbl_rrsoc_store_info r cross join tbl_site_store_format s;

RESULT
--------------------
R-AP-EAST-SMT-4567
R-NY-WEST-XYZ-4567

SQL>
```

---

Function returns a value; you didn't explain how it should look like (which parameters it accepts) so I chose to pass `state`, presuming it is unique within the table.

Sample data:

```
SQL> select * From tbl_rrsoc_store_info;

ST STOR ZON
-- ---- ---
AP EAST SMT
NY WEST XYZ

SQL> select * from tbl_site_store_format;

FORMAT_CODE
-----------
       4567
```

Function:

```
SQL> create or replace function f_test (par_state in varchar2)
  2    return varchar2
  3  is
  4    retval varchar2(18);
  5  begin
  6    select 'R' ||'-'|| r.state ||'-'|| r.store_code ||'-'|| r.zone_name ||'-'|| s.format_code
  7      into retval
  8      from tbl_rrsoc_store_info r cross join tbl_site_store_format s
  9      where r.state = par_state;
 10
 11    return retval;
 12  end;
 13  /

Function created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> select r.state, f_test(r.state) result
  2  from tbl_rrsoc_store_info r;

ST RESULT
-- --------------------
AP R-AP-EAST-SMT-4567
NY R-NY-WEST-XYZ-4567

SQL>
```

Comment: is it in oracle or sql ? and can I make it procedure or cursor for below query ?

Comment: Oracle is database, SQL is language so ... what are you asking, actually? Can you convert it to a procedure? Sure, why not. Or a function. Along with a cursor. No problem. Exact code depends on what you want to get as a result.

Comment: ohh, please make it a function. And what does `dual` means , a table name ?

Comment: The result coming is incorrect,.. First word will be `R` which is fixed one

Comment: Edited the answer, created a sample function, fixed typo (should've been R, not AP). DUAL is Oracle's one-row table. The WITH factoring clause was used just to create sample rows on-the-fly, without creating physical tables.

Comment: BTW, "Nad"? Weren't you "Hud" until recently?

Comment: what is `par_state` parameter here?? yes  I changed my name due to personal reason

Comment: That's parameter name, passed to function, used in its query. I wrote it before you edited the question and posted tables' description. I presume you'd actually pass ID instead; easy to change.

Comment: I guess, I need to run this on `tbl_rrsoc_store_info` table. Because it has ID based on which I need to generate those 18 digit code. Also, I need to insert those generated code in newly created column

Comment: I have changed the function according to my requirement.. I am passing STORE_CODE as parameter and also the where condition like this `where r.STORE_CODE = 9697;` But while doing this, I am getting error as `ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows`. But there is only one store code

Comment: i have modified according to my requirement, but `s.format_code`  value is not coming by using `LEFT JOIN`. here is the updated fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d36f2577d0af789f82895015248ea0e7